# Can I readjust Bootstrap Column spans without JS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this is probably totally against the whole idea of the grid system and the responsiveness but let's just assume I want to do the following anyway: 
I have the layout that you can see in the picture below. 
[image]
The problem is initially the whole image+text part takes `col-md-9` and the twitter feed takes `col-md-2` span on a 1920x 1080 screen. However when displayed on a screen of smaller resolution like 1280x800, I can keep the SAME LAYOUT by changing the image+text part to take up `col-md-5` span. So my question is, is it possible to change the element's col-md class using media queries ? I know CSS cannot touch an elements classes but I thought maybe bootstrap came along with a solution. Otherwise I know I can use JavaScript to get the window size and swap the classes. 
Here is some code should you need. I didnt want to post any code that is not relevant but if you guys need the whole thing, I can set up a jsfiddle prob. 
Thanks ! 1

HTML:

```
<div class="newsfeed">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-11 mainfeed">
                <div class="row top-buffer">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img src="images/chris.jpg" width="190px" />    
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h2 class="pullup">Some text here</h2>
                        <p id="bodypart">Some more text here </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row top-buffer topborder">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img src="images/city.jpg" width="190px" height="280px" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h2 class="pullup">Text text text</h2>
                        <p id="bodypart">Text....</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row top-buffer topborder">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img src="images/alex.jpg" width="190px" height="280px" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h2 class="pullup">Some news text </h2>
                        <p id="bodypart">xxxxxxxxxxx
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 pull-right">
                <!-- Tweet RRS-->
                <div class="tweets pull-right">
                    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/sinanspd" data-widget-id="540693554432323584"
                     width="380px" data-chrome="transparent noscrollbar">Tweets by @sinanspd</a>
                <script>
                    !function(d,s,id){
                        var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                        p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
                            if(!d.getElementById(id)){
                                js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}
                    }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
                </script>
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
/* ----------COMMON STYLING ------ */
body{
    background-color: black !important;  
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
}


.jumbotron{
    height: 340px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("images/banner.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
} 


.nav li{
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 130px;
} 

#nomarginleft{
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.nav a{
    font-family: "Crimson Text";
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 2;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.pull-left{
    margin-left: -350px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}

.pull-right{
    margin-right: -300px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}


.nav{
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
}


.fixed {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0px; 
    height: 50px; 
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: black;
}

/*--------------------- HOME PAGE ---------------- */
#display{
    width: 960px;
    height: 420px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px auto 0px auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: white;
}

#display ul{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:  960px;
    width: 420px;
    list-style: none;
}

#display ul li{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 960px;
    height: 420px;
 } 

#head > p{
    font-family: "Crimson Text";
    font-size: 30px; 
    font-weight: bold;
}

#head{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 220px;
}

.newsfeed{
    width: 86%;
    height: 800px;
    margin-left: -160px;
}

.mainfeed{
    margin-left: 130px;
}
.pullup{
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.top-buffer{
    margin-top: 20px;
 }

.topborder{
     border-top: 1px solid white;
 }


.tweets{
    background-color: rgba(247,12,12,0.3);
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-color: white;
 }

@media (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1300px){

.jumbotron{
    height: 250px;
}

.nav li{
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.nav a{
    font-size: 25px;
}

.pull-left{
    margin-left: -60px;
}

.pull-right{
    margin-right: -40px;
}

#display{
    width: 700px;
    height: 350px;
}

#head > p{
    font-size: 25px;
}

#head{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    display: block;
}

.newsfeed{
    width: 86%;
}

.newsfeed h2{
    font-size: 20px;
}

.mainfeed{
    margin-left: 230px;
}

.newsfeed h2, .newsfeed p{
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.top-buffer{
    width: 800px;
}

.newsfeed .pull-right{
    margin-right:  -120px;
}

.tweets{
    margin-right: -500px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you change your code like below

```
<div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-5">
        <h2 class="pullup">Text text text</h2>
        <p id="bodypart">Text....</p>
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5">
        <img src="images/alex.jpg" width="190px" height="280px" />
    </div>
</div>
```

So now, on bigger screens the screen will we divided 9 cols and 3 cols, on smaller screen sizes it will be 5 cols each.

If you want to change the layout for smaller screen i.e. tablets and screen just user col-sm-xx and col-xm-xx respectively.

Comment: actually I just had the chance to try it and it did not work, it uses the col-lg even on my 13'' mac, any ideas ?

Comment: Because apparently Bootstrap classifies 13'' as lg screen

Comment: That's true. According to http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options your 13" screen comes under lg. In the above code replace lg with md and md with sm.

Comment: unfortunately it did not make any difference. Guess I will need to customize the bootstrap setting. Thanks for your help anyway dude !